Найти текст в кавычках, содержащий русские буквы
Есть строка, в которой могут быть одна или несколько подстрок, заключённых в кавычки. Например: www яя"строка 1" "string 2" и "string3 и string4"ww www
Необходимо найти текст в кавычках, содержащий хотя бы одну русскую букву. В данном примере это"строка 1""string3 и string4"
В данный момент я использую поиск текста в кавычках по выражению '(\")(.+?)\1', после чего в найденных совпадениях проверяю наличие русских букв. А вот составить выражение так, чтобы отбросить текст в кавычках, не содержащих русских букв и сразу получить нужные строки, не получается.
regex101

Это задача конкретного ЯП?

Вы всё делаете правильно. Иначе в данном случае не получится. А регулярка может выглядеть получше - "([^"]*)".

Вам может показаться, что "[^"а-яёЁА-Я]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|"([^"а-яёЁА-Я]*[а-яёЁА-Я][^"]*)" может сработать, но вот в www" ww"строка 1" ничего она не найдёт.

Ну если учесть непарность кавычек, которое все ломает, то можно использовать позитивный просмотр назад и в перед на поиск кавычек https://regex101.com/r/VYfmHJ/4
